# Parsing and fixing time on a messy string database

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have to parse 10K entries from a database.

This database has a field called working hours, that shows the office working hours of car dealers.

The problem is that this field contains descriptive stuff like this:

```
Office working hours from 10 am - 4 pm
Open from 9AM to 5PM
Main Showroom from 10:00AM - 5:00PM
Open 10 AM to 13 PM
Office 10AM to 3PM -- Showroom 9AM to 4PM
```

So you can see the style vary, `am` and `pm` lowercase and uppercase, with and without space, hours with zeros and colon and without it and even `13 PM` a mix between two styles producing a wrong hour. In other words, a total mess. Also, multiple time ranges per line, or not.

I want to transform the whole thing to 24 hour format, like.

```
Office working hours from 10:00 - 16:00 hours
Open from 9:00 to 17:00 hours
Main Showroom from 10:00 - 17:00 hours
Open 10:00 to 13:00 hours
Office 10:00 to 15:00 -- Showroom 9:00 to 16:00 hours
```

I can go infinite number of `if`s like these for every hour:

```
  if ([text containsString:@"7 PM"]) {
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"7 PM" withString:@"19:00"];
  }
```

but this will have billions of lines and will not be efficient. I will have to test for uppercase, lowercase, with and without spaces and to wrong entries.

It must be an easier way to do that...

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout NSDateFormatter.

Comment: I think it will not work. These hours are too screwed. I am trying it right now and it is barely catching a date. Crashing most of the time.

Comment: I'm wondering if `NSDataDetector` could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `NSRegularExpression` and `NSDateFormatter` will come in handy for this job. The results are like this:

[image: Results]

*13PM needs a manual editing, or there may be a way to fix that automatically.*

*Regex is not perfect, it will also capture things like `36 AM`, but date formatter will return `nil`.*

Here's the code, ready to run:

```
NSString *test1 = @"Office working hours from 10 am - 4 pm";
NSString *test2 = @"Open from 9AM to 5PM";
NSString *test3 = @"Main Showroom from 10:00AM - 5:00PM";
NSString *test4 = @"Open 10 AM to 13 PM";
NSString *test5 = @"Office 10AM to 3PM -- Showroom 9AM to 4PM";

NSMutableArray *newStrings = [NSMutableArray array];

// [0-9]+ -> Capture 1 or more digit
// (?:\\:[0-9]+)? -> Capture ":" optionally, if so capture 1 or more digit
// ( )* -> Capture 0 or more whitespace
// (am|pm) -> Case insensitive search, captures aM, Pm, AM, pm

NSString *hourPattern = @"([0-9]+(?:\\:[0-9]+)?( )*(am|pm))";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *miniFormatter = [NSRegularExpression
                                      regularExpressionWithPattern:hourPattern
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                      error:&error];

if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    return;
}

for(NSString *text in @[test1, test2, test3, test4, test5])
{
    NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult *> *matches = [miniFormatter matchesInString:text
                                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

    NSString *textToChange = [text copy];

    for(NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
    {
        NSString *foundTime = [text substringWithRange:result.range];

        NSString *foundTimeOriginal = [foundTime copy]; // This will be used when finding the current range of the text.

        // Step 1: Remove whitespace for parsing.

        foundTime = [foundTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        // Step 2: Make am/pm uppercase.

        foundTime = [foundTime uppercaseString];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];   // You may change it accordingly.

        NSDate *foundDate;

        // Step 3: Detect if it's in hh:mm format or hh format.

        if([foundTime containsString:@":"])
        {
            // hh:mm format

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
        }
        else
        {
            // hh format

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hha"];
        }

        foundDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:foundTime];

        if(!foundDate)
        {
            // There's a problem with parsing (such as 13PM).
            // Proceeding manually...

            continue;
        }

        //NSLog(@"%@ : %@", foundTime, foundDate);

        // Step 4: Convert to 24-Hour

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        NSString *convertedTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:foundDate];

        NSRange currentRange = [textToChange rangeOfString:foundTimeOriginal];
        textToChange = [textToChange stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:currentRange withString:convertedTime];
    }

    [newStrings addObject:textToChange];
}

for(NSString *text in newStrings)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: WOW!!!! BRILLIANT! Thanks! I am trying to decipher the pattern you have used but I do not understand this part `:\\:`

Comment: You're welcome! :)

I've realized that it isn't necessary, `(?::[0-9]+)?` will also work, but the parsing is like this:

`?:` -> Optional
`\\:` -> Escaped ":"